# can't remove blank lines in txt file with R

Tags: r, text, gsub, blank-line

I am doing a text analysis with R and needed to convert the first letters of the sentences into lowercase while keeping the other capitalized words the way they are. So I used the command

```
     x <- gsub("(\\..*?[A-Z])", '\\L\\1', x, perl=TRUE)
```

which worked, but partially. The problem is that for the text analysis I had to convert the pdf files into txt format and now the txt files contain a lot of empty lines (page breaks, returns possibly), and therefore the command I used does not convert the capital letters that appear on the new lines. I was trying to eliminate the empty lines using different combinations in *gsub* with multiple \s, with \r, \n but nothing works. When I do the inspect(x) of the tm-package, the output looks in the following way:

```
[346]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[347]    Thank you.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[348]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[349]    Vice President of Investor Relations                                                                                                                                                                                               
[350]
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help me!

Comment: What do you mean by `the first letters of the sentences`?  How many letters?  All of them?  Some of them?

Comment: Just the first capital one, so it looks like:

        `[341] efficiency and productivity. we think that`

Answer (score 3):

Given your output, the empty lines appear to be separate character strings in a character vector. You need to filter those out using `grep`:

```
empty_lines = grepl('^\\s*$', x)
x = x[! empty_lines]
```

Then you can perform your subsequent analysis, but you probably still need to concatenate the lines first to get a single character string:

```
x = paste(x, collapse = '\n')
```

Comment: @Kohrad Rudolph Thank you! I have tried it out but I get the following error msg: `Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: @Daria There is no call to “meta” in my code, so I don’t know where this error comes from. You’re either using different code, or your R session has redefined some core R constructs in very weird ways.

Comment: I figured it out with 
`x <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)` command. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you mean to use `grepl` instead of `grep`? (The use of `!` suggests that) An alternative might be `trimws(x) == ""`

Comment: @docendodiscimus I actually meant to use `-` instead of `!`, but it comes down to the same thing. I often use `grepl` and combine the result logically with other masks, hence the mistake.

Comment: I personally prefer `grepl` in most situations and would also use it here, since `grep` is problematic when there are no matches, as you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the new lines using `^[A-Z]` and separate the two cases with an or sign `|`

```
x <- gsub("(\\..*?[A-Z]|^[A-Z])", '\\L\\1', x, perl=TRUE)
```

And you can get rid of empty lines either before or after the above step with

```
x <- x[x != ""]
```

Comment: thank you! the latter one has worked for me! however, I still encounter the problem, an example of which I will post in the next comment.

basically there are "extra" spaces left in the beginning of the lines...

Comment: `[283] web tool.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[284]    No, we're not providing any specific targets for the second quarter.                                                                                                                                                                          
[285]    Thank you. `

Comment: You can do `gsub("^ ", "", x)` to get rid of spaces at the start of a line